# Kubernetes can`t access to POD that created by JOB

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I tried create simple JOB in kubernetes by this YAML

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helper.fullname" . }}-notification-about-relese-{{ .Release.Revision }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion | quote }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install,post-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 600 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        {{- if .Values.includeTimestampToPods }}
        timestamp: {{ now.UnixNano | quote }}
        {{- end }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: make-request
        image: "bash:5.2.15-alpine3.18"
        command: ["echo"]
        args: ["test"]
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

And looks like this job complete
[image]

But if I try to look POD logs or try get access to POD exec I have this error
[image]

What it means? How I can fix it?
For me this looks like Kubernetes dashboard don`t have connection to POD

Comment: not able to see above images, can you add the output

Comment: @prasad sure, output is "no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []"

Comment: What's trying to connect to what?  The Job you show neither makes outbound connections nor accepts inbound connections (nor produces image files).

Comment: @DavidMaze this JOB create container and I want to see logs of this container

Comment: Did you run `kubectl logs job/...notification-about-release...`, using the full name of the Job after Helm templating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case problem was not related to YAML file or network. It was because in our infrastructure we have new node that not fully ready to work, because my YAML not contains **spec.template.spec.affinity.nodeAffinity** Kubernetes run JOB POD int this (not fully ready) POD.

Force changed of node for running helped me to fix this issue